# Rxjs throttleTime works unexpected

Tags: angular, rxjs5

(using angular 2 & NgRedux 2 with ngrx 5.0.3)

usersReducer$, articlesReducer$ are Anonymous Subjects I receive from an imported module (ngRedux).

```js
let merge$ = Observable.merge(this.usersReducer$, this.articlesReducer$);
  .do((data) => {
    let time = performance.now();
    console.log('%c REGULAR UPDATE ' + time, 'background: #555; color: #bada55', data);
  });

// TODO : why it doesn't work as expected?!
// The merge$ emits values, and here it only emits once and happens again only
// when the reducers change much later.
this.throttleSub = merge$
  .throttleTime(0.0000000000001)
  .do((data) => {
    let time = performance.now();
    this.refreshData();
    console.log('%c THROTTLE UPDATE ' + time, 'background: #222; color: #bada55', data);
  })
  .subscribe(() => {})
```

Output : [image]

NOTE: If I there is any userReducer$/articleReducer$ emit later, We'll see throttle UPDATE log.

My best guess that things are happening much to fast (that's why I put 0.00000001 in the time between, because 1 ms will emit throttle one time at the start), but the ms difference between them just makes me feel wrong about it.

Would love some help, im so confused.

(with debounceTime(1) instead of throttle, we get only 1 debounce log at the end, it doesn't seems possible that everything is less then 1ms from each other ! there is a server request in the middle !)

---

EDIT:  I've made .timestamp() operator as Mark van Straten stated in his comment.   this is the output:
[image]

---

UPDATE :
I've chained the timestamp to the origin observable, and chained throttleTime into a different subscriber, I think now It's more clear.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttleTime

> Lets a value pass, then ignores source values for the next duration milliseconds.

So the behaviour is that it emits a value, then the timer runs and after the timer has ran to completion it will emit the next emitted value from upstream further downstream.

If you would make a marble diagram of this behaviour it would look something like this:

```
input stream:     --a-b-c---b----c--d----------a-|
throttleTime(50):   a-----| b-----| d-----|    a-|
output stream:    --a-------b-------d----------a-|
```

Comment: It's exactly what I want. if there was an emit, I don't care about any other emits in the next X ms.   the thing is, with 5 ms throttleTime, it should emit  3 times , but it emits only once (at start). (and my outputs say that the timing difference exist).       at the output image, you can see a throttle time of 0.00001 ms, but it still miss the middle emit, it works only at the start and at the end.    :(

Comment: Try using the `.timestamp` rx operator to see emission timings instead of `performance.now`, maybe that shows an discrepancy?

Comment: First, Thanks ! I didn't know about timestamp.    Second, I'm having trouble format my message here, so I made a new image, I really tried make it clear.    it's in the question post .  Thanks :)

Comment: My hunch is that since you are creating two separate subscriptions they are not receiving the same values at exact the same timings. Can you try what happens if you log them from the same stream? (see your original question, i have update your code to let `throttleSub` continue the `merge$`)

Comment: Updated :)  Thank you so much for your help.